# Minimum of $(a+\frac{1}{a})^{50}+(b+\frac{1}{b})^{50}+(c+\frac{1}{c})^{50}$ where $a+b+c=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the minimum of $(a+\frac{1}{a})^{50}+(b+\frac{1}{b})^{50}+(c+\frac{1}{c})^{50}$ where $a+b+c=1$

I tried with the Lagrange Multiplier :

$$\mathcal{L}(a,b,c,\lambda)=(a+\frac{1}{a})^{50}+(b+\frac{1}{b})^{50}+(c+\frac{1}{c})^{50}+\lambda(a+b+c-1)$$

Then

$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial a}&=50(1-\frac{1}{a^2})(a+\frac{1}{a})^{49}+\lambda=0\\\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial b}&=50(1-\frac{1}{b^2})(b+\frac{1}{b})^{49}+\lambda=0\\\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial c}&=50(1-\frac{1}{c^2})(c+\frac{1}{c})^{49}+\lambda=0\end{align}$$

So

$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial b}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial c}$$

But I'm not sure how to make progress after this point. Maybe I can look at the original function and say $(a+\frac{1}{a})^{50}=(a+\frac{1}{a})(a+\frac{1}{a})^{49}$ and substitute an expression in terms of $b$ and $c$, but it doesn't look like this arrives at the minimum.

Comment: I would expect minimum value when $a=b=c=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Given that you know Lagrange Multipliers, I presume you know Jensen's inequality. If yes, notice that $ (x + 1/x) ^{50}$ is concave up, so the minimum occurs at ...

Comment: Second derivative shows that $(1-1/x^2)(x+1/x)^{49}$ is increasing in the interval $(0,\infty)$. Therefore, given $\lambda$, the equation $50(1-1/x^2)(x+1/x)^{49}=-\lambda$ has a unique solution $x>0$. Hence at a critical point $a=b=c$. That is, assuming $a,b,c$ are all positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As

$$
L_{x_k}=n\left(1-\frac{1}{x_k^2}\right)\left(x_k+\frac{1}{x_k}\right)^{n-1}+\lambda = 0
$$

we have as well

$$
nx_k\left(1-\frac{1}{x_k^2}\right)\left(x_k+\frac{1}{x_k}\right)^{n-1}+\lambda x_k = 0
$$

then adding up to $k=1,2,3$ we have

$$
\lambda = -n \sum_k x_k\left(1-\frac{1}{x_k^2}\right)\left(x_k+\frac{1}{x_k}\right)^{n-1}
$$

so
$$
n\left(1-\frac{1}{x_k^2}\right)\left(x_k+\frac{1}{x_k}\right)^{n-1}-n \sum_i x_i\left(1-\frac{1}{x_i^2}\right)\left(x_i+\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^{n-1}=0
$$

for $i=1,2,3$. Now calling $f(x) = \left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n-1}$ we have

$$
\cases{
(1-x_1)f(x_1)-x_2f(x_2)-x_3f(x_3)=0\\
-x_1f(x_1)+(1-x_2)f(x_2)-x_3f(x_3)=0\\
-x_1f(x_1)-x_2f(x_2)+(1-x_3)f(x_3)=0\\
}
$$

or

$$
\left(\matrix{1-x_1&-x_2&-x_3\\ -x_1&1-x_2&-x_3\\ -x_1&-x_2&1-x_3}\right)\left(\matrix{f(x_1)\\ f(x_2)\\ f(x_3)}\right)=0
$$

but

$$
\det\left(\matrix{1-x_1&-x_2&-x_3\\ -x_1&1-x_2&-x_3\\ -x_1&-x_2&1-x_3}\right)=1-x_1-x_2-x_3=0
$$

so for continuity $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f(x_3) = 0$ and the possible answers are

$$
(-1,1,1),(1,-1,1),(1,1,-1)
$$

Comment: I see how you conclude $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = f(x_3)$, but not how you conclude they are all zero--can you explain that?

Comment: Note that for any point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ not pertaining to the restriction, (the plane $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$) the solution should be $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f(x_3)=0$ and $f(x)$ is continuous far from the origin.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, Oups! You're right!

Comment: Could do you explain me why the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

The function $x \mapsto x + \frac1x$ on $x>0$ has a global minimum of $2$ at $x=1$.

The function $y \mapsto y^{50}$ is strictly increasing on $y \geq 2$, so it follows that $x\mapsto \left(x+\frac1x\right)^{50}$ on $x>0$ has a global minimum of $2^{50}$ at $x=1$.

Finally, $x\mapsto \left(x+\frac1x\right)^{50}$ is even, so it has a global minimum of $2^{50}$ at $x=\pm 1$.

---

Turning to your problem, this means
$$\left(a+\frac1a\right)^{50} + \left(b+\frac1b\right)^{50} + \left(c+\frac1c\right)^{50}$$
has global minima of $3\cdot 2^{50}$ at $a,b,c \in \{-1, 1\}$.

As luck would have it, $-1 + 1 + 1 = 1$, so this unrestricted global minimum is also the constrained minimum.